# Possible Effects of a Nuclear Reactor Breach in the Mediterranean

Tags: radioactivity, mediterranean

Double-barreled question which may not precisely belong here!  Input nonetheless greatly appreciated.

My question:  **To what extent would a nuclear reactor breach in the Mediterranean sea affect the sustenance of the ecosystem?  Would its bounty be rendered inedible to humans?**

**Additionally, could Europe adapt without starvation?  Any general thoughts on long-term implications and extenuating factors?**

EDIT::: An example cause might be the catastrophic failure or aggressive destruction in the sea of a typical naval Pressurized Water Reactor used in nuclear marine propulsion.

Comment: Can you identify a specific nuclear power station you are curious about. What level of beech are you interested in? Fukushima like, Chernobyl like, Three Mile Island like, or something else?

Comment: The answer is dependent on the following assumptions: depth and location of burial, age of reactor fuel (typical naval reactors burn very highly enriched uranium for higher energy density, but fresh fuel is relatively benign in that long-lived food-chain isotopes - Caesium and Strontium haven't built up yet in appreciable quantities).

Comment: There's a Journal of Environmental Radioactivity out there, by the looks of it. Please note that humans are insanely adaptable, and will change food sources (or mutate) to North Atlantic fish and non-fish products rather than starve.